# how to write css style for inner image hover?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to write a css style for an image inside a div, but it does not work. My sample code is here

```
<div id="{{$index + 1}}" class="DeviceImages" droppable >    
    <p class="backgroundText">
        {{$index + 1}}
    </p>
    <a class='imagedelete delete' href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
    </a>
    <div
        ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1]"
        class="deviceimage"
        id="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].name}}"
        draggable="true"
        draggable
    >
        <img
            ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].fileType == 1"
            src="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].url}}"
            class="hoverimages"
        />
        <video
            ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].fileType == 2"
            class="hoverimages ImageFiles"
            controls
        >
            <source ng-src="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].url}}" type="video/mp4">
                 Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I am trying like if mouse over on image inside `DeviceImages`, 
then delete should be visible.

```
.DeviceImages div img:hover  {
    display:block;
}
```

But I am not getting

Comment: Please provide the resulting HTML in the browser.

Comment: @VitorCanova here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mssjdb/mL62e0mc/

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector into:

```
.DeviceImages:hover div img {
  display: block;
}
```

which will work when the actual parent is hovered, since in your sample the child 'moves', loosing its hovered state.

---

**Demo**

```css
.DeviceImages:hover div img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="{{$index + 1}}" class="DeviceImages" droppable>
  <p class="backgroundText">
    {{$index + 1}}</p> <a class='imagedelete delete' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a> 
  <div ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1]" class="deviceimage" id="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].name}}" draggable="true" draggable>
    <img ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].fileType == 1" src="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].url}}" class="hoverimages" />
    <video ng-if="slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].fileType == 2" class="hoverimages ImageFiles" controls>
      <source ng-src="{{slotIdVsFile[$index + 1].url}}" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . Here i mean if i hover mouse on image  <a class='imagedelete delete' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a>  should be visible. At first it is display:visible mode

Comment: as these images will be dynamical, i wanted to go through parent div DeviceImages

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can't show the delete option in this way, because it's not in the same level as the image.

You should put your link inside the div that contains the image. In this way, you can show it like the above (I've cleaned the html for simplicity):

HTML:

```
<div class="DeviceImages" droppable>
    <div class="deviceimage" draggable="true" draggable>
        <img class="hoverimages" /> 
        <a class='imagedelete delete' href="#">delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.delete {
    display: none;
}

.deviceimage img:hover ~ .delete {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mL62e0mc/2/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write a custom directive. That is the best for DOM manipulation in angular: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8r4xp6b/22/)

```
<div ng-app="app"> <span mouse-over>Hover me</span>
 <span class="hidden">Delete me</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

javascript:

```
var app=angular.module("app", []);
    app.directive('mouseOver', function() {
      return {
          link: function($scope, element, attr){
              element.on("mouseover", function () {
                  element.next().removeClass('hidden');
          });
      }
    };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I love angular but this kind of stuff is really handled well in jQuery.

Write a custom directive so that you can access jqlite within your angular app. Here's a link for ya:

[jQuery Plugin Directive - Youtube] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Bu73oQQSio